Understanding calculation of slope
I'd like to make a calculation on the slope of house-roofs.
So I have a DEM and drawn a polygon that will mask the raster. This is the side of the roof I want to have an average of, to find out how steep the roof is.
I do understand that the math behind the slop is to take the value of one pixel and compare it to its neighbours etc.
But I end up with image2 and having cells valued 0 and edges valued 424, 862, 102 etc. ie. the white grid.
How do I 'smoothen' this out, so that I can get a value in degrees of the slope.

wcs_data_66f679e688eb4.tif
Polygon is a seperate layer. It appears superpositional to the raster because of clipping image in QGIS.

wcs_data_66f679e688eb4_slope.tif
EDIT(28/9/2024)
DEM pixel-size: 0.04689308269985616867,-0.05700480550036256949
Print from console:
Fetching WCS Data from: https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/dhm_wcs_DAF?service=WCS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCoverage&coverage=dhm_overflade&CRS=EPSG:25832&BBOX=689345.45910234%2C6206720.8035212%2C689382.9735685%2C6206755.0064045&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=600&FORMAT=GTIFF&token=XXXXXX
GeoTIFF saved as: wcs_data_66f679e688eb4.tif
Running GDAL slope command: gdaldem slope wcs_data_66f679e688eb4.tif wcs_data_66f679e688eb4_slope.tif -of GTiff -compute_edges
GDAL slope output: 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Slope file created: wcs_data_66f679e688eb4_slope.tif
Running GDAL info command: /usr/bin/gdalinfo -stats wcs_data_66f679e688eb4_slope.tif
GDAL info output: Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: wcs_data_66f679e688eb4_slope.tif
Size is 800, 600
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
GEOGCS["ETRS89",
DATUM["European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989",
SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6258"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4258"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","25832"]]
Origin = (689345.459102340042591,6206755.006404500454664)
Pixel Size = (0.046893082699856,-0.057004805500363)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  689345.459, 6206755.006) ( 12d 2' 2.50"E, 55d58' 7.41"N)
Lower Left  (  689345.459, 6206720.804) ( 12d 2' 2.42"E, 55d58' 6.30"N)
Upper Right (  689382.974, 6206755.006) ( 12d 2' 4.66"E, 55d58' 7.36"N)
Lower Right (  689382.974, 6206720.804) ( 12d 2' 4.58"E, 55d58' 6.25"N)
Center      (  689364.216, 6206737.905) ( 12d 2' 3.54"E, 55d58' 6.83"N)
Band 1 Block=800x2 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
Minimum=0.000, Maximum=89.276, Mean=13.141, StdDev=24.268
NoData Value=-9999
Metadata:
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=89.276069641113
STATISTICS_MEAN=13.140824304718
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=24.267919204826

Please provide the settings you ran the tool with.

I get the same slope appearance if I upsample my DEM from 50 m, to 5, then slope the upsampled DEM. Are you sure you havent done something similar with your DEM? Did you change the resolution when you clipped it?

The DEM is the original from the Danish national DEM Surface model.

@MichaelR please indicate exactly where you downloaded the DEM raster file from or how exactly you created it and any conversion/transformation/processing you applied on it before the execution of "gdaldem slope" and what is the CRS of the DEM raster layer.

I've also folloed this example 7.3.4 Link and got the same issue.
I understand that black pixels are flat and white are steep, however this particular grid-like pattern seems not to be able to show me a correct value.
I know the exact slope of my test area, so no numbers i've gotten so far has been even remotely close.

Perhaps I need to 'downsample' my DEM from unknown to 50. Do you have a source of reading for that?
